# Refactoring code to use less if statements

Tags: c#, winforms, refactoring

I was just wondering what would be the best approach to refactoring this statement to use less of the condidtions? Im reallt strucggling to clean this statement up without having the same functionality if somone could point me in the right direction i would be very gratefull

```
try
{
    var errorProviders = new List<ErrorProvider>() { epEmail, epAlternative, epMobile, epTown, epLandline, epHouseName, epForeName, epSurname, epPostcode, epCountry, epHouseName, epLocality, epCounty };

    foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (c is SpellBox || c is TextBox)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_ForeName.Text) | !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_SurName.Text))
            {
                if (cmb_Title.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    if (cmb_PrefConTime.SelectedIndex != -1)
                    {
                        if (isPhoneNumber())
                        {
                            if (errorProviders.Any(e => e.GetError(c).Length > 0))
                            { 
                                return false; 
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            epPrefConNumber.SetError(cmb_PrefConNumber, "Error");
                            return false; 
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        epPrefConTime.SetError(cmb_PrefConTime, "Error in: prefered contact time feild");
                        return false; 
                    } 
                }
                else
                {   
                    epTitle.SetError(cmb_Title, "Title"); 
                    return false;
                } 
            }
            else
            { 
                epBothNames.SetError(txt_SurName, "Error:"); 
                epBothNames.SetError(txt_ForeName, "Error:");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())+ "Error has occurred, Please cancel and try again!");
}
return true;
```

If there is a way to use bare minumum conditions to reduce code ?

Comment: My main concern looking at that code is that you only actually use `c` in a single place, deep within the conditions. Why evaluate all of those things every time, rather than once? (I'd also strongly recommend against the "code after the { on a line" formatting, but that's  adifferent matter...)

Comment: @JonSkeet it is used three times actually. Right under the foreach it is used for the first time...

Comment: @MaxPlay: Sorry, yes - I actually meant within that top-level if, not the foreach. My bad. (But everything between testing for the type and calling `Any(e => e.GetError(c))` doesn't involve `c`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I was Initially trying to iterate through the `errorProviders` , but looking back your right there is no real use for c apart from checking the type would it be better to not even have the foreach  and just check the whole panel like   `if (errorProviders.Any(e => e.GetError(panel1).Length > 0))`  ?

Comment: @dave.2: Well I have no idea what `e.GetError` does, so it's hard to tell... but you could *at least* move all the rest of the condition checking outside the loop.

Comment: e.GetError I thought  was getting all of the errorProviders present on the controls. I have all of my error providers stored in a list<Errorproviders> and I just wanted to validate which textBoxes had errors on

Answer (score 1):

If you have to check all those conditions then you have to check all those conditions. Your most egregious issues, in my opinion, are the deep nesting and validating fields that are completely unrelated to the control inside your loop. You can fix the nesting by reversing your if conditions and returning early. For the rest, just move the unrelated validation outside the loop.

```
try
{
    var errorProviders = new List<ErrorProvider>() { epEmail, epAlternative, epMobile, epTown, epLandline, epHouseName, epForeName, epSurname, epPostcode, epCountry, epHouseName, epLocality, epCounty };

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_ForeName.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_SurName.Text))
    {
        epBothNames.SetError(txt_SurName, "Error:"); 
        epBothNames.SetError(txt_ForeName, "Error:");
        return false;
    }

    if (cmb_Title.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {   
        epTitle.SetError(cmb_Title, "Title"); 
        return false; 
    }

    if (cmb_PrefConTime.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {   
        epPrefConTime.SetError(cmb_PrefConTime, "Error in: prefered contact time feild");
        return false; 
    }

    if (!isPhoneNumber())
    {   
        epPrefConNumber.SetError(cmb_PrefConNumber, "Error");
        return false; 
    }

    foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls.Where(x => x is SpellBox || x is TextBox))
    {
        if (!errorProviders.Any(e => e.GetError(c).Length > 0))
        { 
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())+ "Error has occurred, Please cancel and try again!");
}
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your right, I don't need to have all of the validation in the loop, was thinking that i had to check the type first. Was also thinking I probably can just not even use the foreach  and check the panel itself